# show duplicates from each group in temporary table using mysql

Tags: mysql

Can some one help me with a mysql query to show duplicates from each group in temporary table using mysql

sqlfiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8c9c/17

Table

```
TOWN    ID1
town1   1
town1   1
town1   4
town2   1
town2   5
town2   8
town3   1
town3   3
town3   3
```

Required result

```
TOWN    ID1
town1   1
town1   1
town3   3
town3   3
```

I have tried SELECT *  FROM Table1 group by TOWN,ID1
but this removes duplicates and also shows non-duplicate records

Comment: `GROUP BY ... WHERE COUNT > 1`

Comment: Please edit the question to include the query(s) you've already tried, what output they gave you, and how that differed from your expected output.

Comment: @EricHotinger Can you please type the full query?

Comment: @Clive see updated question and sql fiddle

Comment: @SantoshPillai - sure, done.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query you're looking for

```
SELECT TOWN, ID1  FROM Table1 t WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 WHERE TOWN = t.TOWN AND ID1 = t.ID1 ) > 1;
```

Comment: Your query works fine on the sqlfiddle but when I run this on my actual data which is a temporary table I get error  #1137 - Can't reopen table: 't'

Comment: It seems that you can refer to the same table twice in a query done on a temporal table in mysql.

Comment: You mean can't refer same table twice?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html

I can't think of a way of doing the query without refering to the same table twice. Perhaps you should use a regular table instead...

Comment: My temporary table is a join of two tables. Would you know how to do a left join in your query?

Comment: Perhaps something like this...
But i'm not sure, since I can't test it....

Replace the table names and fields.

`SELECT TOWN, ID1  
  FROM Table1 t1 
  LEFT JOIN ( Table2 t2 ) 
    ON ( t1.field = t2.field )
  WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM Table1 tt1
    LEFT JOIN( Table2 tt2 )
      ON( tt1.field = tt2.field )
    WHERE tt1.TOWN = t1.TOWN
      AND tt2.ID1 = t2.ID1 ) > 1; `

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.TOWN, a.ID1 FROM Table1 a JOIN
  (SELECT TOWN, ID1 FROM Table1 GROUP BY TOWN, ID1 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) b 
ON a.TOWN = b.TOWN
AND a.ID1 = b.ID1
```